# Pyodide - How to print results

Tags: javascript, pyodide

I do know a bit of Python, am however new to Pyodide and have no experience in Javascript. I am looking for an easy way to display results in the browser:

```
%% md
a + b = HERE_I_WANT_TO_DISPLAY_THE_RESULT

%% py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1],[2]])
b = np.array([1],[2],[3])
result = a+b
```

Following this Pyodide demo https://alpha.iodide.io/notebooks/300/ I think it might have something do with how to print matrices in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `result =` in the last line of your code. I believe Iodide evals the code you give it and prints out the result.

```
%% py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1],[2]])
b = np.array([[2],[3]])
a+b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also import the `window.document` object and access all of its interfaces. For example, this allows us to manipulate the DOM.

This example show how to insert a `div` into the `body`

```py
%% py

from js import document

div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML = '<h1>This element was created from Python</h1>'
#insert into body as a first child
document.body.prepend(div)
```

The Iodide project is no longer under development, but you can use its Pyodide sub-project. Check out my [tutorial](https://medium.com/@karray/python-in-web-easy-5f7de3813055) on it.